# How to make pins follow a map?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a map with some pins which have `position: absolute`. How do I make pins responsive for all devices? Is there a way to make them follow their parent `div`? I've tried using `media-queries` but it would take ages to style specifically these pins.
Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ymox0h7u/).

HTML:

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
  <div class="map"></div>
  <a class="rpin code-warszawa"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-gdansk"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-kalisz"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-kielce"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-konin"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-krakow"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-ostrow-wielkopolski"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-poznan"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-wroclaw"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .map-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    height: 60vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .map {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url('https://s33.postimg.cc/v6fu8qirj/rst-map.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
  }
  .rpin {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url('https://s33.postimg.cc/6d6a8b4yn/pin.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
    filter: brightness(1) contrast(1.1);
    transition: all .3s ease;
  }
  .rpin:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateX(-40%) scale(1.05);
  }
  .code-warszawa {
    bottom: 55.9282%;
    left: 65.5994%;
  }
  .code-gdansk {
    bottom: 89.858%;
    left: 45.716%;
  }
  .code-kalisz {
    bottom: 45.2392%;
    left: 39.4641%;
  }
  .code-kielce {
    bottom: 27.9065%;
    left: 62.2945%;
  }
  .code-konin {
    bottom: 53.4868%;
    left: 41.3139%;
  }
  .code-krakow {
    bottom: 14.1059%;
    left: 57.1113%;
  }
  .code-ostrow-wielkopolski {
    bottom: 43.573%;
    left: 36.9038%;
  }
  .code-poznan {
    bottom: 56.831%;
    left: 31.9521%;
  }
  .code-wroclaw {
    bottom: 33.6384%;
    left: 32.7036%;
  }
```

Comment: `position: relative`?

Comment: As you can see there is a `position: relative` in `.map-wrapper`.

Comment: But not on the pins

Comment: I don't understand your idea.

Comment: If the pins have absolute positioning then they’re absolutely positioned. If they have relative they’re relative to their parent, since that also has relative set. So set the pins to be relative, not absolute, and they’ll follow the parent wherever it is

Comment: So I set pins to be relative and all the pins changed their positions, I managed to fix it but they are still not moving together with the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the map image **in the HTML** rather than a background image and its wrapper can encompass the image and the pins as well.

Then with the wrapper having `position:relative` the pins can be positioned absolutely (as you have) and all that is needed is to adjust the percentage postion values.

I's also suggest sizing the pins with a `%` so they scale with the map

**Note: the pin placements have not been adjusted in this demo.**

[**Codepen Demo of below code**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ajZMWg)

```css
.map {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.map img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.rpin {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  background: url('https://s33.postimg.cc/6d6a8b4yn/pin.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
  filter: brightness(1) contrast(1.1);
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.rpin:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateX(-40%) scale(1.05);
}

.code-warszawa {
  bottom: 55.9282%;
  left: 65.5994%;
}

.code-gdansk {
  bottom: 89.858%;
  left: 45.716%;
}

.code-kalisz {
  bottom: 45.2392%;
  left: 39.4641%;
}

.code-kielce {
  bottom: 27.9065%;
  left: 62.2945%;
}

.code-konin {
  bottom: 53.4868%;
  left: 41.3139%;
}

.code-krakow {
  bottom: 14.1059%;
  left: 57.1113%;
}

.code-ostrow-wielkopolski {
  bottom: 43.573%;
  left: 36.9038%;
}

.code-poznan {
  bottom: 56.831%;
  left: 31.9521%;
}

.code-wroclaw {
  bottom: 33.6384%;
  left: 32.7036%;
}
```

```html
<div class="map"><img src="https://s33.postimg.cc/v6fu8qirj/rst-map.png" alt="">
  <a class="rpin code-warszawa"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-gdansk"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-kalisz"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-kielce"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-konin"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-krakow"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-ostrow-wielkopolski"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-poznan"></a>
  <a class="rpin code-wroclaw"></a>
</div>
```

Here's a demo I keep around (with a single pin) and content on the pin on hover

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha)

Comment: What if I had a sitiuation like this one - with 2 different wrappers? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/myvf43Lp/)

Comment: Depends on what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I would like to have two divs - one on the left (the map) and one on the right (just a casual div) - both of them with `width: 50%` and wrapped in a container. There I would like this map responsiveness to be still working.

Comment: Thank you for your help! And I am sorry for that but this is the final fiddle with the code I have at the moment. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1ogekv8/)

Comment: Well the same basic technique applies. so it's just a matter of adapting the code.

Comment: I used the same code you provided and tried to adapt it for this example but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: Then it sounds like you have **another** question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176241/discussion-between-kabugh-and-paulie-d).

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever heard of an image map? You can set link areas on a specific position on the image and it's responsive.

To use pins, you should apply them on the picture with a photo editor and place the area above these pins.

Check out this [image map generator](https://www.image-map.net/).

Comment: I need the pins to be clickable.

Comment: What do you want to do with these pins?

Comment: I want to click them and after clicking it allows me to change some state in my code.

Comment: You could give ID's to the areas in the image map and do something by clicking a specific area.